# Codepush for splash screen?

Tags: splash-screen, code-push, react-native-code-push

Can code-push changes files like splash screen of the app?

For example images in the folder Images.xcassets can be overridden ?

Answer (score 2):

Using code-push for the React Native plugin will sync your `JS bundle` file and any `image assets`.

For Cordova Platform : plugin will sync any files which live in the platform-specific `www` folder (including images, etc.)